# Xdebug PhpStorm don't stop breakpoint

Tags: macos, phpstorm, xdebug, breakpoints

- PHP 7.2
- Xdebug 2.7
- Apache/2.4.38
- PhpStorm 2018.1.4
- Mac OS Mojave
- project locally
- installed Xdebug helper in Firefox

I can not debug the code. The code stops at the first line. When I try to go further or put points, debugging ends and PhpStorm writes "connected" and nothing more.

[image: server settings in phpstorm]
[image: php settings in phpstorm]
[image: debug settings in phpstorm]
[image: php settings ini]
[image: first step debug]
[image: validate]

Comment: So .. what Xdebug log tells about such unsuccessful debug session?

Comment: I am not very good at this, but judging by the log I do not see any errors in it. [log](https://yadi.sk/i/HAM2gypl1gJQJQ)

Comment: @LazyOne answer for you)

Comment: Is that the whole log? The last line says that Xdebug stopped at line 4 just fine... and then nothing more (incomplete or truncated log)? I guess some screencast can shed more light on what is happening (maybe it's working or waiting for something, don't know). Right now none of your screenshots show that. Other than that: try debugging some very simple script first (one command per line), something like `<php $a = 1; $b = 2; $c = $a + $b; echo $c;` and see if it will be able to step through that code.

Comment: @LazyOne [whole log](https://yadi.sk/i/YvjdhRwLn29o1g)
[start debug](https://yadi.sk/d/KrEL29rZMlXbYg)
[refresh page in browser](https://yadi.sk/d/D9Lv4BsMcVfmIw)

Comment: I turned off "break at first line in php script"

Comment: Breakpoints got recognized ... Right now I may suggest to: 1) Upgrade (or just try for the moment) to latest stable PhpStorm, which is 2018.3.x or even 2019.1 EAP build 2) You are using PHP 7.2 .. so try Xdebug 2.6.x instead of  2.7 (which was released less than a week ago). I think it should resolve the issue. PhpStorm 2018.2.x with Xdebug 2.6.x works fine (my current setup; I'm on Windows 10 though)

Comment: @LazyOne you saved my nervous system! Thank you!!!! The problem was in the version Xdebug. I installed version 2.6.1 and became happy))

Comment: Upgrading PhpStorm to 2018.3.x will also resolve this (so you can keep using Xdebug 2.7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using PhpStorm 2018.1.x with Xdebug 2.7.

Either upgrade PhpStorm to the latest stable 2018.3.x or downgrade Xdebug to 2.6.x

The problem is in recently changed XML namespace in Xdebug protocol, as of Xdebug 2.7 (`https` instead of `http`). It's fixed/supported since PhpStorm 2018.3 (see [WI-43622](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-43622)).