# Debugging stuck on PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

The debugging is not working anymore on any of my PhpStorm project, when I start listening to incoming connection the script is blocked until I stop to listen to connections, even if I have no breakpoints on my code. And when I put a breakpoint on the first line (it's not working on others lines), the script is indeed stopped, but when I tell him to go to next line it block again (even with the simplest code possible).

I tried to check the debug configuration everything is ok (I used the validator from PhpStorm), the path mapping is also ok, well last week everything worked fine and I changed nothing so ...

Here is my configuration on my php.ini :

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_log=[path]/xdebug.log
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

And here are some part of my xdebug.log when i put a breakpoint on first line then do a step over :

```
[4605] Log opened at 2019-03-12 14:13:50
[4605] I: Connecting to configured address/port: 127.0.0.1:9000.
[4605] I: Connected to client. :-)
[...]
[4605] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="context_get" transaction_id="19" context="1"><property name="$_COOKIE" fullname="$_COOKIE" type="array" [...] </property></response>
[...]
[4605] <- step_over -i 21
[4605] -> <response xmlns="urn:debugger_protocol_v1" xmlns:xdebug="https://xdebug.org/dbgp/xdebug" command="step_over" transaction_id="21" status="break" reason="ok"><xdebug:message filename="file:///[path]" lineno="4"></xdebug:message></response>
[4605]
```

The first response is when it stopped on the breakpoint on the first line, I have everything working fine with variables as "$_COOKIE" logged, then I do the step over, and the script is like stuck. And the problem can't be in the code, I tried with a script with only 2 "echo". I tried to restart apache, I tried to restart PhpStorm, and I tried to restart my computer, nothing changed.

My PhpStorm version :

```
PhpStorm 2018.1
Build #PS-181.4203.565, built on March 28, 2018
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b20 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.4.0-102-generic
```

My php version :

```
PHP 7.1.27-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Mar  7 2019 20:02:03) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.27-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.7.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans
```

Do you have any idea of what is hapening ? (it seems my php version was built last week, maybe it's linked ...)

Comment: I don't know about PHPStorm but in Eclipse every time I use the built in composer stuff it messes my build path all up which messes up the autocomplete.

Comment: 1) Could be path mappings issue (especially if symlinks are involved) 2) You are using PHP 7.1 .. so try downgrading Xdebug to 2.6.x. Either Xdebug or your PhpStorm version may have issues with that 3) Try upgrading IDE to latest stable 2018.3.x or even 2019.1 EAP build. See comments in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55087215/xdebug-phpstorm-dont-stop-breakpoint

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer, it's a non compatibility between phpstorm 2018.1 and Xdebug 2.7.0, as it was signaled on this xdebug bug report : https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1637

I upgraded phpstorm to the version 2018.3, and now everything is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I've been running into the same issue this morning. I believe one of the latest updates to Xdebug (which was officially updated ~6 days ago?) might have broken the build for PHP 7.1.x. I uninstalled the current xdebug version and used a cached version that I had locally inside the apt cache. I think LazyOne might be onto the right track with Xdebug 2.6.1 being the version we need.

Cached packages available here (on ubuntu): `/var/cache/apt/archives/`

Listed and grepped for xdebug - which listed an older cached package that included 2.6.1.

```
cd /var/cache/apt/archives/

ll | grep xdebug
```

And installed the older package using `sudo dpkg -i packagename` where packagename was the previous version I had cached.

Comment: Indeed the problem was xdebug 2.7.0 (or phpstorm 2018.1), I upgraded to phpstorm 2018.3 which fix the xdebug problem and now it works