# Xdebug hangs after first breakpoint

Tags: php, apache, phpstorm, xdebug

Not sure if this is the right place but I have a weird problem with Xdebug. It was working fine until few days ago.

When I hit refresh on the website with Xdebug on, it would not reach the further breakpoints. I narrowed it down to the issue being that once the script hits the first PHP line, it just hangs. So if i put on the breakpoints on the first line in PHP it will hit it, but once I press next it just hangs. I thought it could be the project but I tested this on two different projects.

I've tried re-installing PHP, Apache and Xdebug but same problem keeps happening.

I'm using:

- PhpStorm 2018.1.13
- Xdebug 2.7.1
- PHP 7.0.33

Anybody dealt with this before?

Comment: *"I'm using PHPStorm 2018.1.13 Xdebug 2.7.1 PHP 7.0.33"* Xdebug 2.7.x requires PhpStorm 2018.3 or newer. So either upgrade PhpStorm or downgrade Xdebug to 2.6.x . See https://stackoverflow.com/a/55161822/783119

Comment: You sir @LaZyOne, are a legend!!! Thank you so much!!!!!